# Calling specific superclass

Tags: objective-c

I have `AViewController.h` as below:

```
@interface AViewController : UIViewController

@end

@interface BViewController : AViewController;
- (void)MethodB;
@end

@interface CViewController : BViewController;

@end
```

then I have `AViewController.m` as below

```
@implementation AViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"AViewController.viewWillAppear");
}

@end

@implementation BViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
    NSLog(@"BViewController.viewWillAppear");
}
- (void)MethodB
{
    NSLog(@"show MehtodB");
}

@end

@implementation CViewController

- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewWillAppear:animated]; <--*** I want this line to call AViewController.viewWillAppear directly ***
    NSLog(@"CViewController.viewWillAppear");
    [self MethodB];
}
```

When we run we will get log as follow:

```
2013-08-14 17:37:05.205 P1[12876:c07] AViewController.viewWillAppear
2013-08-14 17:37:05.206 P1[12876:c07] BViewController.viewWillAppear
2013-08-14 17:37:05.206 P1[12876:c07] CViewController.viewWillAppear
2013-08-14 17:37:05.207 P1[12876:c07] show MehtodB
```

But the needed one should be:

```
2013-08-14 17:37:05.205 P1[12876:c07] AViewController.viewWillAppear
2013-08-14 17:37:05.206 P1[12876:c07] CViewController.viewWillAppear
2013-08-14 17:37:05.207 P1[12876:c07] show MehtodB
```

Comment: Why do you want to skip B and why do you need this inheritance chain ?

Comment: If this needs to be done you have a design flaw in your ineritance hierarchy

Comment: @giorashc , Because I want to use BViewController and CViewController in different places, for example, if I create XViewController, and in XViewController, there are two buttons, first button, after you pressed it, BViewController will be opened, for another button, when you pressed it, it will open CViewController.

Comment: Can you elaborate on what this common methods do ? I believe you should rethink your design as view controllers are not meant to be complicated inheritance-wise

Answer (score 0):

That's not possible in straight Objective-C. While you can use the runtime API to figure out the implementation of A's `viewWillAppear` and call it directly this seems like a fragile approach and not generally recommended for production code.

Can you elaborate a little of your reasons to do this?

Comment: My reason to do this is because AViewController have group of methods that BViewController need, so I don't need to rewrite again, then I assigned BViewController to inherit AViewController, so that I can use the needed group of methods from AViewController. For CViewController, I also used the same logic I described above because there are some methods in BViewController and all methods in AViewController that I need to use.

Comment: Do you have any suggestion for me about how to achieve this problem in a different way, which is better?